# What font is used in the book Quarks and Leptons

Tags: math-fonts

I've been reading the book quarks and leptons and the maths font used in the book is growing on me. Here is a snippet from the book

[image]

However, I cannot seem to find the maths font for this book. Anyone have any idea what the font is?

Comment: which book on that subject? do you have pdf of it or just on paper?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you have a pdf? If yes, check the used fonts in the pdf file ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using a pdf that I have found online

Comment: @Mensch I will attach the pdf i have found

Comment: then use pdffonts utility or teh font menu in your pdf reader and see the fonts used (unless the pdf is just a collection of bitmap scans of a real book)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think its a scan of a book

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It was published in 1983 is that too old?

Comment: well that almost predates TeX, also it's not clearly a legal copy, so I choose not to look at it too closely.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oops

Comment: I think this should be closed as a duplicate of the generic what-font question, probably the exact font is not available in current digital formats, possibly use a times-ish math font such as newtxmath or stix2.

Comment: Looks like Times.  That was a workhorse font in the mid 20th century.

Comment: @barbarabeeton What times font is the math font in, ive been looking around and I cant find one

Comment: It probably isn't a Times font that is now available to TeX.  What it looks like to me is the Times font used on the Autologic APS-5, a CRT-based typesetter that set its output on photographic paper (and requiring a darkroom to process).  I don't know of any of these machines in use since the beginning of this century.  The Times clone most often recommended these days is in two parts: `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton is there any way to recreate this font so you can use it in latex or is it under some copyright restrictions?

Comment: The mechanism for actualizing this font was either patent-protected or closely held by the Autologic company.  In any case, it was a purely commercial font.  I don't know anyone who might know how to decode and reimplement it for a modern laser printer.  It would definitely not be an easy or "direct" translation.